# A basic level log question

Tags: logarithms

Answer is 3/2 to this question:

[image]

But how? And why?

Comment: Do you know how to use log properties?

Comment: In particular $\log_{a}\left(a^b\right)=b$

Comment: I know all the log properties @SeanRoberson

Comment: It holds $2=4^{1/2}$. Does it help you?

Comment: Suppose that $(12)^r = s$.  Then, since $(12) = (2^2 \times 3)$ you have that $2^{(2r)} \times 3^{(r)} = s.$  Notice that the exponents that are assigned to the bases of $(2)$ and $(3)$ in the expression $2^{(2r)} \times 3^{(r)} = s$ are in the **proportion of** $[2r ~: ~r].$

Comment: That's it! Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

That's a pretty easy question, you just need to know how to use some log properties.

Let's get started.

$$\log_{12} ({2^3 \cdot 3^\frac{3}{2}})$$

$$\log_a (p\cdot q) = \log_a p + \log_a q$$

$$\log_{12} ({2^3 \cdot 3^\frac{3}{2}}) = \log_{12} ({2^3}) + \log_{12} {(3^\frac{3}{2})}$$

$$\log_a (p^q) = q\log_a p $$

$$\log_{12} ({2^3 \cdot 3^\frac{3}{2}}) = 3\log_{12} ({2}) + \frac{3}{2}\cdot \log_{12} {(3)}$$

Now we just need to handle the $\log_{12}{(2)}$ and $\log_{12}{(3)}$.

$$\log_{a}{(x)} = \frac{\log_b {(a)}}{\log_{b} {(x)} } $$

Where, $b$ is any base that you want.

Let's handle $\log_{12}{(2)}$ first:

$$\log_{12}{(2)} = \frac{\log 2}{\log 12}$$
Important: $\log_{10} x = \log x$.

Solving $\log 12$:

$$\log 12 = \log (2\cdot 6)$$
Using the log properties that I showed above for multiplication:

$$\log (2\cdot 6) = \log 2 + \log 6$$
$$\log (2\cdot 6) = \log 2 + (\log (2\cdot 3))$$
$$\log (2\cdot 6) = \log 2 + (\log 2 + \log 3)$$
$$\log (12) = 2\log 2 + \log 3$$

So, $\log_{12}{(2)} = \frac{\log 2}{\log 12}$ which is equal to:

$$\log_{12}{(2)} = \frac{\log 2}{2\log 2 + \log 3}$$

Now you are going to do the same to:

$$\log_{12} (3)$$

I will leave the rest as an exercise.